# If $x^5-bx^3+cx^2+dx-e$ can be expressed as the product of a perfect square and a perfect cube then prove following

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, quadratics

If $x^5-bx^3+cx^2+dx-e$ can be expressed as the product of a perfect square and a perfect cube then prove that 
$$\frac{12b}{5}=\frac{9d}{b}=\frac{5e}{c}=\frac{d^2}{c^2}$$

My attempt is as follows: 
$$E=x^5-bx^3+cx^2+dx-e$$
$$E=(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)^3$$
$$E=x^5-\left(2\alpha+3\beta\right)x^4+\left(3{\alpha}^2+6\alpha\beta+{\beta}^2\right)x^3-\left({\alpha}^3+6{\alpha}^2\beta+3\alpha{\beta}^2\right)x^2+\left(2{\alpha}^3\beta+3{\alpha}^2{\beta^2}\right)x-{\alpha}^2{\beta}^3$$
$$x^5-bx^3+cx^2+dx-e=x^5-\left(2\alpha+3\beta\right)x^4+\left(3{\alpha}^2+6\alpha\beta+{\beta}^2\right)x^3-\left({\alpha}^3+6{\alpha}^2\beta+3\alpha{\beta}^2\right)x^2+\left(2{\alpha}^3\beta+3{\alpha}^2{\beta^2}\right)x-{\alpha}^2{\beta}^3$$

So we obtain five equations

$$\left(2\alpha+3\beta\right)=0$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{-3}{2}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

$$3{\alpha}^2+6\alpha\beta+{\beta}^2=-b$$
$$\text {Dividing by ${\beta}^2$}$$
$$3\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}+6\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+1=\frac{-b}{{\beta}^2}$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{b}{{\beta}^2}=\frac{5}{4}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

$${\alpha}^3+6{\alpha}^2\beta+3\alpha{\beta}^2=-c$$
$$\text {Dividing by ${\beta}^3$}$$
$$\frac{\alpha^3}{\beta^3}+6\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}+3\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{-c}{{\beta}^3}$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{c}{{\beta}^3}=\frac{-45}{8}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

$$2{\alpha}^3\beta+3{\alpha}^2{\beta}^2=d$$
$$\text {Dividing by ${\beta}^4$}$$
$$2\frac{\alpha^3}{\beta^3}+3\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}=\frac{d}{{\beta}^4}$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{{\beta}^4}=0\tag{4}
\end{equation}

So $d$ is coming as $0$ and this is where I am stuck because for $$\frac{12b}{5}=\frac{9d}{b}=\frac{5e}{c}=\frac{d^2}{c^2}$$ $d$ should be non-zero because $\dfrac{12b}{5}=3\beta^2$ is non zero.

Please help me.

Comment: $E = x^5-\big(2\alpha+3\beta\big)x^4+\big(\alpha^2+6\alpha\beta+3\beta^2\big)x^3
-\big(3\alpha^2\beta+6\alpha\beta^2+\beta^3\big)x^2
+\big(3\alpha^2\beta^2+2\alpha\beta^3\big)x-\alpha^2\beta^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\alpha=-\frac{3}{2}\beta,$$ we obtain:
$$E=\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\beta\right)^2(x-\beta)^3=x^5-\frac{15}{4}\beta^2x^3+\frac{5}{4}\beta^3x^2+\frac{15}{4}\beta^4x-\frac{9}{4}\beta^5,$$ which gives
$$b=\frac{15}{4}\beta^2,$$
$$c=\frac{5}{4}\beta^3,$$ $$d=\frac{15}{4}\beta^4$$ and $$e=\frac{9}{4}\beta^5.$$
Can you end it now?

For example, we need to prove that:
$$12bc^2=5d^2$$ or
$$12\cdot\frac{15}{4}\beta^2\cdot\left(\frac{5}{4}\beta^3\right)^2=5\cdot\left(\frac{15}{4}\beta^4\right)^2.$$